# In a c# program, how does one access properties of observable collections?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF app that amongst other tasks, retrieves incident information (I work for a police department) and displays it on an electronic form for the user.

In the incident information there are three observable collections of data related to the incident:  `Suspects`, `Victims` and `Arrests`.

Each OC has its own type. All three OC's are bound to combo boxes and display properly when the data is retrieved.

The arrest combo box is only supposed to display the arrest number and it works correctly.

Here is the code for the XAML that defines the data binding for the Arrest combo box:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Form104CModel.Arrests}"
```

The item source, Form104CModel.Arrests, is populated when incident data is retrieved (rr has all the incident data.)

```
this.Form104CModel.Arrests = rr.Incident.Arrests;
```

As I said above, the list of arrest numbers displays properly, so I know they are in the OC.

Here's where the problem occurs:  The form has to also show a list of the arrests, so it has to loop through the arrest numbers to retrieve each arrest record.  I thought I could do it this way:

```
foreach (Arrest arrest in this.Form104CModel.Arrests)
{
     this.ArrestNumberValidator.ValidateArrestNumber(arrest.ArrestNum);
     .
     .
     .
}
```

But when I debug the app, the `arrest.ArrestNum` field is null!  Yet the arrest numbers show on the form.

Apparently there is something going on with the binding of the Combo Box to the Observable Collection which allows the arrest numbers in `this.Form104CModel.Arrests` to display, and I'm not doing it somehow.

Can anyone explain exactly what I am missing here?

Comment: It seems like you are setting the `Arrests` property to a new collection each time. Are you implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`? Otherwise you won't see the new items on screen. If you re-set the source property to a *new* collection, it doesn't matter whether the collection is an `ObservableCollection<T>` or any other `IEnumerable`. This only matters when you add items to the same collection.

Comment: Are you sure that your `foreach` is running after `this.Form104CModel.Arrests = rr.Incident.Arrests;`? There's nothing special about accessing items in an observable collection, so there must be something else going on.

Comment: show the item template of combobox, Is it really bound to `arrestnum` property itself? How is `ViewModel` created? Are there being multiple instance of view models being created somehow? When and how is foreach invoked? There are lot of missing info,

Comment: It is impossible to answer your question without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. In addition, in construction that MCVE, you should eliminate all of the domain-specific aspects. There is no need for us to know anything about the application (incident information) or where you work (police department). These are just distractions, and make it harder to see what the actual question is. Plus, by simplifying the problem in that way, you may in fact simplify it enough for you to solve it yourself. But if you don't, then at least you'll have a good question to post here.

Comment: To all:  Never mind folks.  I found the problem.  In building the combo boxes for suspects, victims and especially arrests, I had added a null item as the first item in the list, which would enable the user to reset any selection made.  It was the null item that the foreach loop was referencing first, and since there was no arrest number there, it looked like the data had disappeared.  I should have noticed that the count for the arrest OC was 7, when there was only 6 arrests linked to the incident.  Sorry to waste everyone's time.